# Bit manipulation using shifts as well as and

Tags: binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I have been given the hexadecimal number 0xAA and been told to perform the following operations on it, in order:

Shift right by 3
And with 0x18
Shift left by 2

Here are my steps for doing this:

1.) Represent 0xAA in binary

0xAA = 1010 1010

2.) Shift right by 3

0001 0101

3.) Represent 0x18 in binary

0x18 = 0001 1000

4.) Perform 0001 0101 and 0001 1000

0001 0101 & 0001 1000 = 0001 0000

5.) Shift left by 2

0100 0000

And that is my final answer, 0100 0000. However, the answer I am told I should get is 0111. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong, or how I should get that answer. I was hoping someone could tell me where I am  going wrong. Thank you all very much.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting in my post, the operations I must perform are: 1.) Shift right by three 2.) And with 0x18 3.) Shift left by 2

Comment: If this are all the given information: Your result is right.

Comment: Your answer looks right to me for the given steps. However, I get `0111b` if performing these operations: `(0xAA >> 3 | 0x18) >> 2`... maybe whoever told you `0111b` meant to do that instead? You can't even get `0111b` if you sign-extend the `0xAA` in an 8-bit register or rotate instead of shift! (Also, you could never have anything that ends in `11b` after left-shifting twice, so something is definitely up).

Comment: This is all the given information, thank you Joshua, I appreciate your help

Comment: lungi, if I am understanding correctly, you get 0111 if you shift right by 2 instead of left by 2 at the last step. My understanding would lead me to believe that these steps would result in 0100, why do you fill in ones to the right?

Comment: In order to figure out what the person who told you the answer was `0111b` was doing, I also had to change the bitwise AND to an OR. I'm just trying to solve this mystery with you :) I take it this was some homework or something. As someone who occasionally creates assignments/tests/whatever, those are totally the kinds of mistakes we make. We make a version of a question, create a solution, and then change the question afterwards, forgetting to update the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I assume there was some kind of typo or miscalculation by my professor, you are right on point. I simply wanted to ensure that I didn't have some fundamental flaw in my understanding of basic bit manipulation. Thank you for your help lungj!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I am calculating the correct result, and it is the expected result that is incorrect. Thank you all for your help.